# Native method not found / runtime exception

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am doing Android programming using Java-Eclipse Luna on Windows 8.1, also, I am using native environment (C++). I am getting a "Native method not found" error which I don't know the reason behind. here is my code:

my .java file:

```
epackage com.example.abstractnewocvpart3;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class AbstractNewOCVpart3Activity extends Activity {

float dataArray[] = new float[4];
float mat[] = new float[4];
private static final String    TAG = "OCVSample::Activity";
private CameraBridgeViewBase   mOpenCvCameraView;

public static native float[] MatFcn(float[] x);

private BaseLoaderCallback  mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");

                // Load native library after(!) OpenCV initialization
                System.loadLibrary("myLib");

                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
    };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_abstract_new_ocvpart3);

    dataArray[0] = 0;
    dataArray[1] = 1;
    dataArray[2] = 2;
    mat = MatFcn(dataArray);
    mat[0] = mat[0] + 1;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.abstract_new_ocvpart3, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

now my .cpp native library:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core_c.h>
#include <opencv2/core/types_c.h>

#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


extern "C" {
//static jfloatArray  MatFcn(JNIEnv *pEnv, jclass clazz, jfloatArray x);
 jfloatArray JNICALL MatFcn(JNIEnv *pEnv, jclass clazz, jfloatArray x)
{
jfloatArray jfloatArr = x;
jfloat *floatArr = pEnv->GetFloatArrayElements(jfloatArr, 0);
pEnv->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(jfloatArr, floatArr, 0);
return jfloatArr;

}
}

/** The bossy JNI_OnLoad() method */
      jint  JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved) // this method is called when the native library is loaded
{
    JNIEnv* env;
    if (vm->GetEnv(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&env), JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK){
        return -1;
    } // end of if()

    JNINativeMethod nm[1];
    nm[0].name = "MatFcn";
    nm[0].signature = "([F)[F";
    nm[0].fnPtr = (void *) MatFcn;

    jclass cls = env->FindClass("com/example/abstractnewocvpart3/AbstractNewOCVpart3Activity");
    //Register methods with env->RegisterNatives. Methods that you create. methods registration
    //should be done in the JNI_OnLoad() method to guarantee that native methods are registered
    //before being invoked.
    env->RegisterNatives(cls, nm, 1);
    env->DeleteLocalRef(cls);
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;

}// end of JNI_OnLoad()
```

At run time, I get an exception in my Logcat saying that native method not found.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't that function name be `Java_com_example_abstractnewocvpart3_AbstractNewOCVpart3Activity_MatFcn`?

Comment: if I do so I get this error: "Symbol 'MatFcn' could not be resolved" at the line where I register this method in the .cpp file ( line: nm[0].name = "MatFcn"; )

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed the part where you call `RegisterNatives`. Seeing as how no one else has answered this yet, perhaps I'll later be able to get up an Android development environment on my computer here to try your code. In the meanwhile, a few guesses: could it be that your `JNI_OnLoad` is never called because `onCreate` is called before your `mLoaderCallback` has a chance to load the native library?

Comment: @Christian. When using the OpenCV library, the native library can only be declared after initializing the OpenCV one (i.e. inside the  'mLoaderCallback' ) which is implemented outside the 'onCreate'. I tried to change in my code's configuration but I reached no way!

Comment: can you make your call to MatFcn right after you call `System.loadLibrary("myLib");` ?

Comment: Well the problem is that the library isn't loaded because the "BaseLoaderCallback" is never called, but it should be executed automatically after launching the application, right?